# Set variable on django start and have it available in all views

Tags: python, django, model

I have a variable that is set based on a database query ( It changes about every 6 months) , but I find it quite inefficient to be querying the database every time I require it. I believe there must be a more efficient way to handle this. Context processor, maybe?

The current core looks like this, I currently call *active_period* once per every register in my database :

```
class RegistrationQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def active_period(self):
        try:
            active_period = AcademicPeriod.objects.is_active()[0]
            return self.filter(academic_period=active_period)
        except:
            return self
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation about [Database access optimisation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/optimization/) or [caching API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api).

```
from django.core.cache import cache

class RegistrationQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def active_period(self):
        try:
            active_period = cache.get('active_period')
            if not active_period:
                active_period = AcademicPeriod.objects.is_active()[0]
                cache.set('active_period', active_period)
            return self.filter(academic_period=active_period)
        except:
            return self
```